# How to avoid splitting of field values in faceted search in solr

Tags: solr

While facet-based searching, in the search result doc element has field with values in the form of string(of more than words) but in the facet, every value is in the form of string with single word.
Following is the sample solr search result,

```
<result>
   <doc>
       <str name="fieldA">abc1 efg1 ijk1</str>
       <str name="fieldA">abc2 efg2 ijk2</str>
       <str name="fieldA">abc3 efg3 ijk3</str>
       <arr name="fieldD">
           <str>abc1 efg1 ijk1</str>
           <str>abc2 efg2 ijk2</str>
           <str>abc3 efg3 ijk3</str>
       </arr>
   </doc>
</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
    <lst name="facet_queries">
       <int name="fieldB:ab">some_number</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="facet_fields">
       <lst name="fieldA">
            <int name="abc1">1</int>   I want <int name="abc1 efg1 ijk1">1</int>
            <int name="efg1">1</int>
            <int name="ijk1">1</int>
       </lst>   
    </lst>
</lst>
```

Schema.xml has fields - fieldA, fieldB, fieldC and fieldD like following

```
  <field name="fieldA" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
  <field name="fieldB" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
  <field name="fieldC" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
  <field name="fieldD" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

and

```
  <copyField source="fieldA" dest="fieldD"/>
  <copyField source="fieldB" dest="fieldD"/>
  <copyField source="fieldC" dest="fieldD"/>
```

I want the facet values of string of multiple words just like in the string of multiple words in the field values. Please suggest.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to change the type of your field from `type="text_general"` into `type="string"` for the facet search.

If you can't do it for that field you can create a new string field (it could be a copyfield) and then apply the facet on that one.

Comment: Can you explain why `text_general` is splitting the values and `string` doesn't ?

Comment: to explain it simply, the string field does not know that " " space is a separation char. for him it is just a char like any other.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark thanks a lot. Your solution solved my problem on solr 7.6.0